# jQuery not detecting when image is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code to choose between 2 ways of displaying an image:

```
slider.find("img").each(function() {
    $(this).on("load", function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("src"));
        var imgW = $(this).width(),
            imgH = $(this).height();

        console.log("width: "+imgW+" + height: "+imgH);

        if (imgW/imgH <= sliderW/sliderH) {
            $(this).removeClass("slide-responsive").addClass("img-responsive");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("slide-responsive").removeClass("img-responsive");
        }
    });
});
```

This basically uses one class if the proportion of the image is bigger than the one of the space where it is displayed, or another one if it is not.

I'm using .on("load") to detect when the image is loaded, because it should only be able to recognize width and height of a loaded image.

The problem I am having is that it works only for an image that is stored locally, but not for 2 others that are loaded off the internet. For the external images, it always returns a width and height of 0.

There are 2 console.log commands there to verify 1) that it is really picking the right image (I check for the src attribute), and 2) the sizes detected. 1) is working fine, so I know that the selectors are ok.

My guess is that I'm not using on("load") correctly, but I can't tell what is wrong from the jQuery docs. Where do I go from here?

Comment: @VotetoClose, that was it. The slides are initially not shown, so jQuery doesn't detect sizes. It did work with JavaScript: var imgHeight = img.get(0).height;
var imgWidth = img.get(0).width;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the image have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` on it?

If so, this can cause issues with jQuery detecting the element(s), especially if it has `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

probably the answer is the fact that you forget to trigger your on function. Instead of `.load` `.on` needs a trigger.

Which probably means that you have 2 options.

Either use .load

```
slider.find("img").each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("src"));
        var imgW = $(this).width(),
            imgH = $(this).height();

        console.log("width: "+imgW+" + height: "+imgH);

        if (imgW/imgH <= sliderW/sliderH) {
            $(this).removeClass("slide-responsive").addClass("img-responsive");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("slide-responsive").removeClass("img-responsive");
        }
    });
});
```

Or use a trigger:

```
slider.find("img").each(function() {
    $(this).on("load", function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("src"));
        var imgW = $(this).width(),
            imgH = $(this).height();

        console.log("width: "+imgW+" + height: "+imgH);

        if (imgW/imgH <= sliderW/sliderH) {
            $(this).removeClass("slide-responsive").addClass("img-responsive");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("slide-responsive").removeClass("img-responsive");
        }
    });
}).trigger("load")
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. I didn't know that "load" needs a trigger. It kind of beats the point to add it tho, as I wanted to know when the images were loaded. I'll stick to load() in the future!

Comment: The advantage of on is that you can indent events. And trigger functions that are in them on ALL occassions. for example .on("ready") and .on("resize").

P.S: Think you made a typo ;) because .load does not need a trigger .on needs one.

P.P.S: Think about accepting my answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/load-event/, there could be issues using `.load()` with images:

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache